# MSN Health & Fitness doesn't save data

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-735

I'm using MSN Health & Fitness as pedometer. Everything was fine until recently. I noticed app is not saving data anymore and I have lost data for past 3 days. Today I discovered that pedometer is not saving measured values when it resets on the beginning of the new day.

How to fix that? Can I get back lost data or is it permanently lost? (I also noticed it shows yesterday values on the main screen in comparison with yesterday values, so I suppose that data are there somewhere...).

I'm using Windows Phone 8.1 on Lumia 735.